# How to make the text in front of the eqution or figure number become a hyperlink？

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I found that in many journals not only the number but also the text such as `Fig` or `Eq` can be a hyperlinked so one can be directed to the equation or figure by clicking the hyperlink. This is what is looks like:

[image]

Now I want to my document's hyperlink to look similar, but I only know when the `hyperref` package is loaded, using the `\label` and `\ref` command can create the hyperlink via the number.

How can I create the hyperlink like in the journal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set the hyperlink manually using a combination of `\hyperref[<label>]{... \ref*{<label>} ...}` or `\autoref{<label>}`.

The following example highlights this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure}\label{fig:first}
  \caption{Another figure}\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

See \hyperref[fig:first]{Figure~\ref*{fig:first}} and~\ref{fig:second}.
Alternatively, see \autoref{fig:first} and~\ref{fig:second}.

\end{document}
```

The starred version of `\ref*` removes any hyperlinking, which you want to avoid inside `\hyperref`.

Comment: It works, Thanks  for your answer and grammar corrections :) @Werner